# How do I set the active selected project in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've developed an Eclipse plugin which allows users to add projects.
I'm looking for a way to automatically select (in the Navigator and Project Explorer) the project that was just created. As it is now, if users create a new project, the selection in Navigator and in Project Explorer are still set to the old project that was selected before we added this new project, while in Package Explorer behaviour is as expected - the new project is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to call

```
BasicNewResourceWizard.selectAndReveal(resource, window);
```

where `resource` is any `IResource` derived object (such as an `IProject`)
and `window` is the workbench window.

This call is usually included at the end the creation wizard (but can be called anytime).

`BasicNewResourceWizard` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource` package in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin.

Comment: BasicNewResourceWizard is not recognized in my code. what import does it require?

Comment: I added the package and plugin to the answer and corrected the selectAndReveal method arguments.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have an issue now of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on the org/eclipse/ui/wizards/newresource/BasicNewResourceWizard class. do you know how to solve that? i get the error only at runtime - while at compile time everything seems ok.

Comment: You need to add the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` to your plugin's dependencies